# nav bar not coapse in ipad

Tags: css

i am working on a website and i have an issue that nav bar is not collapse in Ipad. Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="navbar-heade">
<div class="logo pull-left"><a href="index.html" class="header-logo"><img      src="assets/images/logo-color-1.png" alt="" /></a></div>
<button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navigation" class="navbar-toggle template-navbar">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>


<nav class="navigation collapse navbar-collapse pull-right">
<ul class="nav-links nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="index.html" class="main-menu" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="" class="main-menu" target="_blank">Link 1</a></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="main-menu">Main Menu<span class="fa fa-angle-down icons-dropdown"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu template-dropdown-menu-1">
<li><a href="" target="_blank" class="link-page">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="" target="_blank" class="link-page">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="" target="_blank" class="link-page">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="" target="_blank" class="link-page">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="main-menu">main Menu<span class="fa fa-angle-down icons-dropdown"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu template-dropdown-menu-1">
<li><a href="" target="_blank" class="link-page">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="" target="_blank" class="link-page">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

i am using Bootstrap v3.3.5 (http://getbootstrap.com) version

Comment: pls help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Are other examples working? Like this one: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse

Comment: all functionality is working fine except nav bar collapse in ipad

Comment: Well... Maybe iPad's browser doesn't support the attributes that are used to make collapsible navbar?  There has to be something wrong with the browser.

Comment: but i am checking on here: http://www.responsinator.com/. Here you can see ur webiste in all device.

Comment: Check the browser support for your version of bootstrap and also... There is a newer version of bootstrap and it supports some browsers http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/browsers-devices/#mobile-devices Make a simple example and check its collapsible functionality.